# "Inheriting" DataAnnotations from multiple models when creating a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations on my model class **Base1** that formats DateTime type.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
 public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

When I create another model from **Base1** and **Base2** models

```
public class Combined
    {       
        public Base1 Name1 { get; set; }
        public Base2 Name2 { get; set; }
    }
```

DateTime format in Name1 instance changes to default (data and time).

Is there a way to "inherit" DataAnnotations from base models so I don't have to format display data on View layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not a direct answer to what you're asking, but I would highly recommend using display/editor templates. This type of thing is exactly what they have been designed for. For example you can create a template that handles `DateTime` (place it in `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`). Then in the template:

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, Model.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Then of course use it like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(...)
```

If you have multiple templates you can name them and chose which one to use. Same goes for display templates.

Comment: When I was playing with your solution I realized that all I need to solve that issue is to use @Html.DisplayFor(). Thanks for your answer. I will look deeper into this approach.

Comment: @CookieMonster Awesome, I'm glad I could help. Let me know and I'll provide more details :)